PHP custom shortcode is appending the word "Array". How do I get rid of this?
I have a custom shortcode that shows the last updated date of my posts. The shortcode is ouputting the proper date but is appending the word "Array"? How do I get rid of this?
//Last Updated Date Blogs
function show_last_updated( $content ) {
  $u_time = get_the_time('U');
  $u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U');
  if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 86400) {
    $updated_date = get_the_modified_time('m/d/Y');
    $updated_time = get_the_modified_time('h:i a');
    $custom_content .= '<p class="last-updated-date">Updated: '.$updated_date.'</p>';
  }
  $custom_content .= $content;
  return $custom_content;
}
add_shortcode( 'the_content', 'show_last_updated' );


Remove the line where you append the array... $custom_content .= $content;

If you think $content contains something valuable，you'll need to present what data it holds and what desired result you want.

Did you get a bit confused here, between shortcodes, and the WP hook/filter system? the_content is one of WP's main filters. You could name your shortcode the same - but I wouldn't, first of all to avoid confusion, and second of all, to have it reflect the actual purpose a bit better - something like last_update or similar. The parameter shortcode callback functions get passed in, is usually called $args. [...]

[...] If you don't need to process any shortcode arguments, then you can simply ignore that parameter in your function. Appending it to the output however, regardless of how it was named, will only get you the word Array - because the arguments are an array, and this is what happens, when you force an array value into a string context.

Thank you guys! These were all very helpful and it work by just getting rid of $custom_content .= $content;
